# Why do all elements of my list point the last element added at the end of a loop?

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
population= [stream_rules.StreamRules for n in range(len(buffer))]
l= [[] for n in range (len(buffer))]
for i in range(0, len(buffer)):
    length = random.randrange(2, len(buffer[i]), 1)
    split = random.randrange(1, length, 1)
    population[i].split = split
    for j in range(0, length):
        l[i].append(buffer[i][j])

    population[i].ch= l[i]


for i in range(0, len(population)):
    print(population[i].ch)
```

Notice that `StreamRules` is a class that has `ch`, `split` as variables.
what I'm trying to do is copy every line of `buffer` in every line of the list `L` then passing it to `population[i].ch`.

The problem is when I try to print (in order to verify) in the last loop I find that all the `ch` elements point to the last element that I copied from `buffer`. I can't see where is the problem. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: is `population` supposed to be a list of instances? In that case shouldn't it be `stream_rules.StreamRules()` with parenthesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the parentheses when creating `population` - you're not actually creating instances. It should be `population= [stream_rules.StreamRules() for n in range(len(buffer))]`. All of the elements are the same because the elements of `population` aren't instaces, so you created static members of `StreamRules` called `ch` and `split`, and static members are the same for all class members.